# MySQL syntax - selecting selecting rows based on multiple arguments?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Have a look at the following query:

```
SELECT title,rating from books, book_genres WHERE
books.id = (book_genres.book_id = (book_genres.book_id=2));
```

I'm trying to display a table which shows the title and rating for books under a certain genre.

The genre for each book is defined in book_genres with a relationship between foreign keys for each book and genre.

I'm not being returned any errors when I try to execute the query - I just get an empty set. So I'm on the right track, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. How would I get the desired result?

If anything is unclear, let me know and I will clarify.

Comment: Where you are selecting from multiple tables, you usually have to use either JOIN or UNION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT b.title, b.rating from books b
LEFT JOIN book_genres bg ON(bg.book_id = b.book_id)
WHERE b.book_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT b.title, b.rating from books b, book_genres bg
WHERE bg.book_id = b.book_id and b.book_id = 2
```